# React native WebView: dynamically loading static assets

Tags: ajax, react-native, webview, three.js

I am trying to dynamically load files in a WebView.  I can use an ajax call out to fetch from a server but can not figure out how I would load the resources if they are in the assets folder.

DETAILS:
I am loading a three js scene from the local file system using:

```
 <WebView source={{ uri: "file:///android_asset/test.html" }} />
```

I have maybe 10 local models in the asset folder and would like to load a specific model when the user selects it.  How would this be done using a THREE js loader?  If a loader cant be used, can I fetch the model and pass it into the loader manually?

Basically is it possible to have a webview access the local file system in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const localHtmls = [require('../htmls/test.html'),
  require('../htmls/test2.html'), ...];

// Do your logic here to find the index
let theHtml = localHtmls[0];

<WebView
  source={theHtml}
  style={{flex: 1}}
/>
```

Make sure the path in `require` is correct.

Comment: Once in that webview how do i fetch local resources?  I can load a base html page with js but I have ten files and want to load one of them when user selects that file?

Comment: I edited the answer now providing multiple html files.

Comment: I have 10 twenty MB models but dont want to front load them.  Is there anyway to access the local file system from within a webview?  Sorta of like an ajax call but to " file:/// "  Is it possible for the user to interact with the android OS file System while in a webview